# Binding/Passing request parameters from controller to client in Micronaut

Tags: parameters, path, binding, micronaut

I am trying to build a gateway app using Micronaut.
On the client side it connects to a REST API while on the controller side another app is sending requests> I am able to stream the requests but not the path variables/parameters.
As an example, how would I pass the path parameter received in the controller, to the client.

```java
@Controller("/bintray") 
public class BintrayController {

    private final BintrayLowLevelClient bintrayLowLevelClient;

    private final BintrayClient bintrayClient;

    public BintrayController(BintrayLowLevelClient bintrayLowLevelClient, 
                             BintrayClient bintrayClient
                              ) {
        this.bintrayLowLevelClient = bintrayLowLevelClient;
        this.bintrayClient = bintrayClient;
    }


    @Get(uri = "/packages/{paramFromRequest}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_STREAM) 
    Flowable<BintrayPackage> packages() { 
        return bintrayClient.fetchPackages();
    }

}
```

```java
@Client(BintrayConfiguration.BINTRAY_API_URL) 
public interface BintrayClient {

    @Get("/api/${bintray.apiversion}/packages/{paramFromRequest}") 
    Flowable<BintrayPackage> fetchPackages(); 

}
```

Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 3):

You can dynamically get both path and query parameters with `HttpRequest` :

```java
@Get(uri = "/packages", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_STREAM) 
Flowable<BintrayPackage> packages(HttpRequest<?> request) { 
    return bintrayClient.fetchPackages(request.getParameters());
}
```

As for the Http client, I would not go for a declarative one but a low-level one and manually add the query params and what you want in the http query

Answer (score 2):

It isn't exactly clear to me what the question is, but this may help.  Instead of this in your controller...

```
    @Get(uri = "/packages/{paramFromRequest}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_STREAM) 
    Flowable<BintrayPackage> packages() { 
        return bintrayClient.fetchPackages();
    }
```

You could do this...

```
    @Get(uri = "/packages/{paramFromRequest}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_STREAM) 
    Flowable<BintrayPackage> packages(String paramFromRequest) { 
        return bintrayClient.fetchPackages();
    }
```

In the client, instead of this...

```
    @Get("/api/${bintray.apiversion}/packages/{paramFromRequest}") 
    Flowable<BintrayPackage> fetchPackages();
```

You could have this...

```
    @Get("/api/${bintray.apiversion}/packages/{paramFromRequest}") 
    Flowable<BintrayPackage> fetchPackages(String paramFromRequest);
```

Comment: Thank you for that one, it seems to work fine. 
I believe the @client fetchPackages() should also get the parameter like: bintrayClient.fetchPackages(paramFromRequest); 
Is that correct?

Comment: "I believe the @client fetchPackages() should also get the parameter" - No, `@Client` would not make mention of request parameters.  The `fetchPackages` method inside the class that is marked with `@Client` would, as shown in the code sample.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: ok, thanks. Will I be able to modify the body of the response with the declarative client, or should I directly use a low-lever client?

Comment: "Will I be able to modify the body of the response with the declarative client, or should I directly use a low-lever client?" - That might depend on what kind of modifications you want to do the body and what you need access to in order to do that modification.  It might be that a filter would be the right solutions but it is hard to say without knowing what you are trying to accomplish by modifying the response.  Some modifications to the body can be made by modifying the model that is returned from an endpoint.

Comment: I am trying to build an abstraction layer that converts a "not-so-restfull-API" into a restfull one. So for example, I will have to correct the property names returned in the json when they are incorrect or badly described.

Comment: "So for example, I will have to correct the property names returned in the json when they are incorrect or badly described." - I would do that using the relevant Jackson annotations on your model classes.  That way you don't need a filter or any other special component.  You can annotate your existing components and get the desired JSON out of them.

Comment: Can I use the Jackson annotations with the flowables? I dont quite get the difference between the GET notation used in your example with flowable and implementations using HttpResponse<....>.

Comment: "Can I use the Jackson annotations with the flowables?" - Yes.